# In Ubuntu, where is the Thunderbird 3 installation folder?

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

I made a shortcut to the file that I used to install and run Thunderbird, but the shortcut looks weird. Where is the file that is used to run, but not install Thunderbird?

Comment: How did you install Thunderbird 3?

Comment: I went to http://www.getthunderbird.com/, downloaded the file for Linux, extracted it and clicked thunderbird.

Comment: I think he needs installation folder that that app has been installed like in Window, is it ?

Comment: it is, the folder where the app was installed

Comment: On top, why isn't Thunderbird in Applications -> Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have extracted the Thunderbird .tar.bz file you should have a `thunderbird` directory.  Inside of the directory  there is a `thunderbird` file.  That is the file you should execute to run Thunderbird.  So:

```
/path/to/thunderbird/thunderbird
```

The application is never "installed" in a traditional sense.  It just runs from wherever you extracted the archive file.

**Edit:**
Clicking on a file in linux does not run it by default.  You have manually execute the application.  You can create a launcher icon which will launch the application by right clicking on the Ubuntu desktop, selecting *Create launcher*.  Enter *Thunderbird* for the name, */path/to/thunderbird/thunderbird*(acutal path of course) as the command.  You can eve change the icon to one of the icons in `/path/to/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/`.  Select *OK* and you should have a new launcher icon to run Thunderbird.

The .tar.bz file you downloaded from http://getthunderbird.com is not an installer like you would get on Windows, it is just the files needed to run the application.  Thus, there are no installed shortcuts or icons anywhere on your desktop.   If you want to install an application like you would on Windows, you should use the default packages provided in Synaptic/Add-Remove Applications, or use a `.deb` file like the one [jweede suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/130246/in-ubuntu-where-is-the-thunderbird-3-installation-folder/130249#130249).

Comment: Why doesn't the thunderbird-bin icon look like a thunder bird which is the official thunderbird icon?

Comment: I clicked it, it's not running Thunderbird.

Comment: Apologies... the file to run is called `thunderbird`, not `thunderbird-bin`  I was going from memory off my Windows machine till I could get to a linux box.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually set it up, you might want to give the [Thunderbird DEB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThunderbirdNewVersion) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of default installation directories (32-bit Linux):

Mozilla Suite   `/usr/lib/mozilla-<version>`

For example: `/usr/lib/thunderbird-<version>`

Examples of default installation directories (64-bit Linux):

Thunderbird `/usr/lib64/thunderbird-<version>`

For example: `/usr/lib64/thunderbird-2.0.0.21`

Comment: still not there

Comment: firefox-3.5.3 is there though

Comment: a mozilla folder is there too, but no thunderbird inside it